# How do I move a file from the downloads folder to a folder on my Desktop (I need this to work on every computer)

Tags: python

I am a beginner to python so I thought I'd make something fun

```py
import os
import time
import random
import webbrowser
import pyautogui
import subprocess
import ctypes
import shutil
import pathlib

webbrowser.open('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iik25wqIuFo')
time.sleep(3)
ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, "You have been rickrolled", "Good Job", 0)

os.path.expanduser(r'~/Desktop')
os.mkdir('rickroll')
webbrowser.open('https://appraw.com/dl/MaEhadnv8a')
os.path.expanduser('~/Downloads')
time.sleep(10)
shutil.move('~/Downloads/Rick Roll0.mp3', '~/Desktop')
```

what is supposed to happen is, it opens a rickroll on YouTube then it waits for 3 seconds and then it sends a msg box after they click "OK" on it, it goes to the Desktop and then creates a folder called rickroll. It then goes to a website that downloads a short clip of the video and "Tries" to put it in the rickroll folder I say tries because it doesn't

instead it says it cant find the file

the error I get is

Exception has occurred: FileNotFoundError
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/Downloads/Rick Roll0.mp3'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

File "C:\Users<MY USERNAME>\Desktop\Code Name Destiny.py", line 20, in 
shutil.move('~/Downloads/Rick Roll0.mp3', '~/Desktop')

I have tried a lot of things like swapping out the ' for " and getting rid of and, adding commas and tried a new module (that ended badly) and i tried getting rid of the ~ that didn't work either been stuck on this issue for a couple on days now

I hope someone can help me, and thank you for anyone that tries and helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use expanduser and capture use the result

```
path1 = os.path.expanduser('~/Downloads/Rick Roll0.mp3')
path2 = os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop')
shutil.move( path1, path2)
```